# automorphism group of forgetful functor $Vect_k^{gr} \to Vect_k$

Tags: category-theory

Is the automorphism group of the forgetful functor $Vect_k^{gr} \to Vect_k$ (finite dimensional $\mathbb{Z}$-graded vector spaces) equal to $(k^\times)^{\mathbb{Z}} \wr Sym(\mathbb{Z})$ (wreath product)?

Comment: Do your graded vector spaces have finitely many nonzero components, or do the components just need to be finite-dimensional?

Comment: Hint: Yoneda Lemma.